# How to print double with all decimals in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, double, precision

First of all this is no duplicate. I searched the web but no answer is sufficient.

I want to print a double. So I have to convert it to a QString. I want to have no scientific notation and 0.1 should print 0.1 and 1/3 should print as much 0.33333... as double is capable to represent. Unfortunately I can find only solutions with fixed precision, which leads to eiter a capped 0.333333 (end after specified p loosing precision) or an unnecessary zero filled 0.100000.

I know I could max out the precision and drop all trailing zeroes, but isnt there a nice solution, which just prints max possible but min necessary precision?

**Edit:** I guess I need to clearify a few things. This question is not about to map the space of real numbers into single, double or whatever precision floating point numbers. It is about the inverse: the mapping of the 64 bit double precision floating point space into our beloved realworld real numbers. Since the former is a subset of the latter there is, in theory, absolutely no problem doing this.

Comment: Precision of floating point types is different on different intervals. Learn more about IEEE754 floats here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Well my questing is not that highly computer scientific. I just want to get that double to a string representation, no matter how unprecise mapping of real numbers to the double space is. Anyway thanks for the reminder an showing up the need for clearification.

Comment: Why, may I ask, do you want such accurate precision? If you want real precision, you need a CPU that can handle it better. You need a supercomputer!

Comment: I dont want real precison. I want my string output to have exactly this precision, that makes the string have exact the same value as the double represents. Nothing much scientific, no supercomputers needed. Again misunderstood.

Comment: You ask for contradictory things: "all decimals" and "0.1 should print 0.1". The closest double to the real number 0.1 is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. Do you want that printed, or "0.1"? Every finite double number has a terminating decimal representation, no infinitely recurring digits. The result of 1.0/3.0, in double arithmetic, is exactly 0.333333333333333314829616256247390992939472198486328125.

Comment: Youre right in my thoughts I was at 1.0000.. x 10 ^ -1. I want to have exactly those numbers you describe.

Comment: I am facing issue which look like above problem. I have double value 1.00 but when I used QString::Number() I will get only '1' because it emits trailing zeros after decimal, I can set precision in QString::Number but then every value will set that precision even use enter number with whatever precision digits .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try simplest thing `QString::number(1.0/3.0, 'g', 17);` or when using `std::ostream` there is [std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) used to control number of decimals for `operator<<`

Comment: I want the user to be able to copy the number an reuse it. So no scientific notation. I know format 'f', but result is not as expected, since it does not depict the size of the mantissa, but the amount of the digits after comma. Why are you using exactly 17?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r The user will not be able reuse the real number by copy/paste through the text form, it will lose precision. When you read the paper in the first comment (i did a year ago) the you will find that 17 digits is for the double to recover it.

Comment: Try `qDebug() <<  QString::number(0.000000000000000001, 'f', 17);`. You Absolutely missunderstood my point. This is purely engineering. Nothing much scientific.

Comment: If you need science behind, read the [What Every Computer Scientist ...](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) posted in first comment, there is your answer. I can only recommend you for your program that when user wants to copy the number put into clipboard the underlying `double` not a text (`QString` or whatever) itself.

Comment: This would be fine, sadly Qt supports text and mimedata only.

Comment: @Radek For IEEE 754 64-bit binary, the normal representation of C++ double, if you capture at least 17 significant digits in the String representation, you will recover the original double.

Answer (score 1):

### The Problem

Contrary to the other comments and answers here, this is a very reasonable request, and the question seems pretty clear. Floating-point conversion to strings should usually have the properties described in the question, instead of the primitive form found in the C and C++ standard libraries. You should not need to specify the precision, as the algorithm should use what is necessary. To expand a bit, say you pick a fixed precision of 6. Then you print three 64-bit floats without scientific notation, (the ones closest to) 0.1, 1.0/3.0, and 1.0/3000.0:

```
0.100000
0.333333
0.003333
```

There are a couple problems here. With 0.1, there are unnecessary zeros printed at the end. It is much cleaner and just as accurate to print `0.1`. With the other numbers, the value has been truncated. A 64-bit float can represent 15+ decimal digits, but we just printed 6. If you convert the string back to a float, you won't get the same value. So let's choose a precision of 17:

```
0.10000000000000001
0.33333333333333331
0.00333333333333333
```

Now we are representing the value of 1.0/3.0 better, but 0.1 only looks worse. It would be just as accurate and look much better to print `0.1`. Also, we are still truncating 1.0/3000.0. There is no fixed precision you can pick to make numbers print nicely.

### The Solution

There is an old and somewhat slow algorithm (Dragon) to solve this problem:

http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf

And there is a much faster algorithm, Grisu, published in 2010, but it needs to fall back to an algorithm such as Dragon for 0.5% of floating-point numbers:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1809028.1806623

Several language implementations have adopted Grisu for printing floating-point numbers (such as Firefox's and Chrome's JS engines and Rust's standard library). There's also an algorithm just published in 2016, Errol, that improves upon Grisu and doesn't need to fall back to Dragon. It is so new it probably hasn't seen any adoption yet:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2837654

I needed good floating-point printing today, so I've been experimenting with Qt, and it doesn't seem that Qt can do what the question asks for. `QString::number` and `QString::arg` both use a poor algorithm.

In the Qt 5.7 new features list, there is this note:

> Added the ability to convert a floating point to its shortest, exact string form, without having to pre-calculate how many digits that is; QVariant uses this

In my tests, using `QVariant{floatValue}.toString()` seems to meet the requirements, except for still using scientific notation with very small and large numbers. Here is a C++ library by the inventor of the Grisu algorithm that looks excellent (and it allows choosing when it uses scientific notation):

https://github.com/google/double-conversion